# How can I use four time equal (ex. ====) in excel formula

Tags: excel, formula

I'm unable to use below formula in excel

```
400+rate÷400×principal====
```

Ex.
Do this in calculator:

400+9.05÷400×10000

Now press four times the equal button.  Answer is 10936.17.  But I'm unable to do this in Excel.  I hope someone may help me.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to write `====`, just one `=` is enough. Also, use `*` and not `x`, use `/` and not `÷`.

If you want the result to be `10226.25`, you need some math predecessors using brackets `()`.

Enter this equation in a cell:

```
=(400+9.05)/400*10000
```

This gives the expected outcome:

```
10226.25
```

Comment: Already done by me.
but hopeless

please try your formula in excel 

and in calculator as said by me.

Comment: `=(400+9.05)/400*10000`. See my new answer.

Comment: Yaaaa
This gives the expected outcome
10226.25 



but if i press equal button four times in calculator then outcome is 10936.17
so now tell me how can I get 10936.17 outcome in excel formula.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you press = in the calculator you are multiplying the result by the operation before it

1. 400+9.05=409.05 you will get the result without =in the calculator if you only press ÷
2. 409.05 ÷ 400 = 1.022625 this is the number that each time you press = will multiply the result in the calculator
3. you write X 10000 and first = 10266.25 first result
4. second = is 1.022625 X 10266.25 second result 10457.62
5. third = is 1.022625 X 10457.62 third result 10694.22
6. fourth = is 1.022625 X 10694.22 fourth result 10936.18 your outcome
   In Excel you have to write:
   `=(((400+9.05)/400)^4)*10000` to have the same outcome

Comment: I think here "^4" used for multiplying (four times equal button)

If I want multiplying 3 times then value will be "^3"


Again thanks "yass"
your reply useful for me.

Answer (score 0):

It's true that Excel can be used as a Calculator up to certain extent,, but it's not created to act like a Calc,, always remember ever calculation begins with = sign followed either by Function or data. 
So finally you should write your Formula like this,

=(400+9.05) /(400×10000)

Comment: Thanks "Rajesh S" for your reply but my problem already solved by "yass".
 By your formula
=(400+9.05)/(400*10000) outcome is 0.000102263
& by =(400+9.05)/400*10000 formula outcome is 10226.25

Comment: It's okay iTech no problem, we all are trying to help each other. 
Ive put 400 *10000 within the brackets bcozz of a basic Mathematics rule BDMAS, did you remember this!

Answer (score 0):

You might find a parameterised version useful:

[image: SO43427212 example]

The inputs are shown in blue, the output in F2 where the formula is:

```
=C2*((A2+B2)/A2)^D2
```

D2 is effectively the number of equals signs depressed on your calculator.